# How to add JSON objects to a string of array in my images service dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have image and file service to take picture i used this for camera functionality https://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/
angular.module('ob3App')

```
.factory('FileService', function() {
    var images;
    var IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY = 'images';

    function getImages() {
        var img = window.localStorage.getItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY);
            if (img) {
                    images =  JSON.parse(img);
                } else {
                    images = [];
                }
                return images;
            };

    function addImage(img) {
            images.push(img);
            window.localStorage.setItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(images));
        };

    return {
        storeImage: addImage,
        images: getImages
    }
})



.factory('ImageService', function($cordovaCamera, FileService, $q, $cordovaFile) {

    function makeid() {
        var text = '';
        var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'; 
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        return text;
    };

 function optionsForType(type) {
        var source;
       /* switch (type) {
          case 0:
            source = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
            break;
          case 1:
            source = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
            break;
        }*/
        return {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source,
            allowEdit: false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };
    }

function saveMedia(type) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        var options = optionsForType(type);     
            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageUrl) {
                var name = imageUrl.substr(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                var namePath = imageUrl.substr(0, imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                var newName = makeid() + name;
            $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newName)
                .then(function(info) {
                    FileService.storeImage(newName);
                        resolve();
                }, function(e) {
                    reject();
                });
            });
        })
      }
    return {
        handleMediaDialog: saveMedia
    }
});
```

And i have a list of 3 items on swiping any of this item this buttons will be displayed, Which will invoke my camera function and take picture

```
<ion-option-button ng-click="addImage()"class="icon ion-android-camera"></ion-option-button>
<ion-option-button >
  <img ng-src="{{urlForImage(separateImage)}}" width="90px" height="90px"/></ion-option-button>
<ion-option-button ng-click="gridPage()" class="icon ion-ios-grid-view"></ion-option-button>
```

i will get an array of image names

```
["image1.jpg",
 "image2.jpg",
 "image3.jpg"]
```

i need a json in this formate, With the detail that in which item i took this image.

```
[{"ItemNo":"1",
  "FileName":"image1.jpg"},
 {"ItemNo":"1",
 "FileName":"image2.jpg",},
 {"ItemNo":"3",
 "FileName":"image3.jpg"}];
```

Could some one help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be

```
var myArray = ['image1.jpg','image2.jpg','image3.jpg'];

var result = myArray.map(function(name, i) {
  return {
    ItemNo: i,
    FileName: name
  };
});

console.log( JSON.stringify(result) );
```

You would [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array.
If the *ItemNo* should start with *1*, use

```
return {
  ItemNo: (i + 1),
  FileName: name
};
```

Comment: i need to add it inside this function     function addImage(img) {
            images.push(img);  
            window.localStorage.setItem(IMAGE_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(images));
        };

Comment: i should get the itemNo by swipe any of the 3 items in that list